# MonetDB Query Performance - Multi-Table Joins vs. Single-Table Predicate Selections

Tags: performance, query-performance, monetdb

I use MonetDB to execute IR-Tasks and I have come across the following issue I do not fully understand!

In this setting I created two very simple tables.

**Dictionary Table: (3 267 008 tuples)**

```
CREATE TABLE "ir"."dict" (
    "tid"  INTEGER       NOT NULL,
    "term" VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT "pk_dict" PRIMARY KEY ("tid")
);
```

**Dictionary History Table: (113 574 247 tuples)**

```
CREATE TABLE "ir"."dict_histu" (
    "tid"     INTEGER,
    "added"   TIMESTAMP,
    "removed" TIMESTAMP,
    "df"      INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT "fk_dict_histu" FOREIGN KEY ("tid") REFERENCES "ir"."dict" ("tid")
);
```

And executed the following queries.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT dict_histu.tid, dict_histu.df FROM dict 
    JOIN dict_histu ON dict.tid = dict_histu.tid 
        WHERE dict.tid IN (25,26,27) 
        AND dict_histu.added <= timest 
        AND (dict_histu.removed IS NULL OR dict_histu.removed > timest)
        LIMIT 100;
```

Execution Time (~1,2s)

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT tid, df FROM dict_histu 
    WHERE dict_histu.added <= %timest% 
    AND (dict_histu.removed is NULL OR dict_histu.removed > %timest%) 
    AND dict_histu.tid IN (25,26,27) 
    LIMIT 100;
```

Execution Time (~4,7s)

Intuitively I would have assumed the second approach to be faster
because there is only one table concerned and an unchanged number of predicates and candidates to be eliminated.

**My Question: Why does the first query outperform the second? What is happening behind the scenes (literature available?)? How can this observation contribute to c-store database design in general(best-practice)?**

Unfortunately the trace-logs are way to long to be attached!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tested running several queries in parallel ? I'm having same kind of issues while running a query over a single table.

Comment: Well, actually I have but only to a small extent and i could not make out any noticeable differences if running several clients in parallel. But indeed the performance seems to be associated with the limit clause. The differences in execution time vanish if it is removed.

Comment: I think you should look at (or share) the EXPLAIN of these queries (the trace is indeed too long). One obvious question: are you running both queries with hot data? (i.e. run both a couple of times before you measure them). One thing I notice (although I don't think it should account for such a big difference): in Q1, the selection on `tid` is faster because on the pkey of a smaller table, and the subsequent join very fast because on f-p key (whose hash is likely to be materialized).